# Polymorphic Associations in SQL

Tags: sql, polymorphism, mariadb, associations

I'm creating a project with big database of Movies and Series, both in seperate tables. Now I have other tables like Country for specifying production country of movie or/and serie. If I want to do this in many to many relation it requires connection table one for movie and one for serie. It would look like this:
[DB with separate connection tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YZn8.png).

It is many tables, so I was searching for other solutions and I found this [article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-mapping-to-rdb/) and the "Using one data entity per class" method seems to be best for me. I implemented it like that: [DB with combined connection table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7CCC.png).

The second implementation seems to be good, but there's a one problem I'm facing and that's a complicated inserts. To insert new Movie, I need first to add new Production and second to insert Movie and pick just created Production ID.

My question is could it be fixed in some way ? Can't it be auto incremented from Movie table ?

I'm using 10.1.36-MariaDB and I'm realy sorry for my poor english :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Movies and Series have only one column that is different (boxoffice), it makes sense to put the two tables together and let boxoffice be `NULL` for series.  I don't understand the need for `Production`, but it seems to add as much complexity as it saves.  Try to get rid of it.

I suggest that the id for `Country` be the standard 2-letter codes.  This will be more compact and eliminate some stuff.

The is no good reason to have an `id` for a connection table.  See [*many-to-many tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) .  Those tips will speed up many of your queries, and save space.

"Polymorphic" and many other neat-things-in-a-textbook don't necessarily work well in Relational Databases.